# Two paths homotopic to each other in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that  the following two statements **are equaivalent**: (i) **any closed path in $D$ is homotopic to zero**, and (ii) **any two paths in D that have common ends are homotopic to each other**.

My approach is: Let $D \subset \mathbb C$ be a domain and $\gamma : [\alpha, \beta] \to D$ a closed path. Let $a \in D$ be a given point. Assume that $\gamma$ is homotopic to that point $a$. Is it enough to prove that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point $b$ in $D$ for any $b \in D$.

Want to show that $\gamma_a(t) = a$ is homotopic to $\gamma_b(t)=b$. Then the result would follow, since homotopy is a equivalence relation:

Let $H(t,s) = (1-s)a+sb$. $H$ is continuous, and $H(t,0) = a$, $H(t,1) = b$, and $H(\alpha,s) = H(\beta,s)$. The problem is how to continue from there.

Comment: @DanielFischer... I had to edit the question so it would be much clearer. But I am still lost on what to do.

Comment: @J.R. If you have two paths $\beta,\gamma$ from $a$ to $b$, then $\beta\ast \gamma^{-1}$ is a closed path (where $\ast$ is the composition of paths such that the endpoint of the first path is the initial point of the second, and $\gamma^{-1}$ is the path $\gamma$ traversed in the other direction). If every closed path is nullhomotopic, can you see how you might use a homotopy $\beta \ast \gamma^{-1} \simeq c$ to obtain a homotopy $\beta \simeq \gamma$ (with fixed endpoints)?

Comment: @DanielFischer, am trying to understand that. But how is the closed path you defined be homotopic to zero?

Comment: By assumption. We assume property (i), and from that deduce property (ii). And when that is done, we prove the implication $(ii) \implies (i)$ [which is easier].